# Overriding and weaking access modifiers

Tags: java, overriding, jls

According to the [JLS 8.4.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance
>   method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> - C is a subclass of A.
> - The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
> - Either:
>
>   - m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same
>       package as C, or
>   - m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2),
>       such that m3 overrides m2.

This doesn't appear to contradict the following code:

```
public class Main {

    public void f() { }
    public static class A extends Main {
        protected void f() { }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/cHKzcB)**

But it's not compiling, even though the overridden version of the method `f()` has the `protected` access modifier, as said in the second point of the rule I provided. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The justification for this is provided lower in the JLS, in [8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> The access modifier (§6.6) of an overriding or hiding method must provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, as follows:
>
> - If the overridden or hidden method is public, then the overriding or hiding method must be public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method is protected, then the overriding or hiding method must be protected or public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method has default (package) access, then the overriding or hiding method must not be private; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Note that the section you've quoted in your question essentially states "the method's access modifier in the base class must not be private", and doesn't relate to the overriding method's access modifier at all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override a method with more restrictive access modifier. The method f() was declared with access modifier `public` but you are trying to override it with `protected` modifier which is more **restrictive**. Change

```
public static class A extends Main{
        protected void f(){ }
    }
```

to

```
public static class A extends Main{
        public void f(){ }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is I'm interested in the formal `JLS` explanation. Now I can't see how JLS prevents this code.

Comment: You absolutely *can* override a method with a weaker access modifier, assuming that by "weaker" you mean "more public" - for example, in a test I've just overridden a protected method with a public method. It was fine. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean more restrictive modifier .

Comment: Right, in that case I agree.